# How to fix npm to find correct node enviorment?

Tags: upgrade, homebrew

I have installed homebrew via boxen. I did not know that `npm update -g` is a bad thing to do, as npm runs amok trying to update itself. Hence, npm stopped working. I am now trying to get node and npm back to work again.

I have installed the node via homebrew:

```
$ brew unlink node && brew link node
Unlinking /opt/boxen/homebrew/Cellar/node/0.10.26... 5 symlinks removed
Linking /opt/boxen/homebrew/Cellar/node/0.10.26... 4 symlinks created
```

Yet npm claims that

```
$ npm
nodenv: version `v0.10.26' is not installed
```

Running nodenv indeed shows that the current version is not found:

```
$ nodenv versions
v0.10
v0.10.21
v0.6
v0.6.20
v0.8
v0.8.8
```

I am confused as to why nodenev shows all the versions it does.

How do I fix nodejs and npm?

Comment: You probably want to uninstall it not just link - note that you can really only use one package manager as they will conflict as shown here

Answer (score 2):

I consider this a workaround, if there is a way to get node upgraded the brew way, I appreciate it.

It seems that boxen in its standard configuration only provides v0.10.21 yet once `npm` updated itself, it expects v0.10.26.

I tried to reconfigure boxen to install node yet failed.

I then went along and installed NodeJs manually over the pgk provided by [nodejs.org](http://nodejs.org/) and globally installed node 0.10.26. Then `nodenv` was able to find that version and by setting

```
nodenv global v0.10.26
```

npm started working again. I then had to reinstall certain packages not expecting that v0.10.26 version, e.g. bower version.